# Is it possible to prevent a certain flow from being auto-enabled when upgrading a managed package?

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, isv, package-install

What the title says. I have a managed package that has a flow. Some of my subscribers have a different flow that does the same thing but uses a slightly different process so they don't need my flow enabled. I have many more subscribers that rely on my flow. If I set the flow to enabled in my package, all my subscribers have it enabled in their orgs. If I set the flow to disabled, all of my subscribers will have it disabled in their orgs. There is no sweet spot that I'm aware of that respects whether or not the flow is enabled or disabled during the upgrade process.

Is this expected behavior?